# How can I create keyboard-shortcut to open Git Bash in Windows?

Tags: git-bash

I want to create a shortcut that open Git bash by pressing ctrl + alt + T. Then, it launches git bash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you're asking about Windows.

Just set an Explorer hotkey on the Start menu shortcut.

[image]

Comment: I can't edit this shortcut key here. What to do?

Comment: @AhmedTareque I’m guessing you’re looking at the Properties window of the Git shortcut in the All Users Start Menu (under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`)? If so, you can’t edit it because that requires admin permissions. You’ll need to create your own shortcut to Git first.

Comment: @Dai plz tell how to open it with a particular folder path.

Comment: @Ajayjangid That's the `Start in` parameter box.

Comment: Yes,but can't change always like this. actually I was looking for keyboard_shortcut which does what this :- **right-click > open-git-bash-here** does.

Comment: This worked for me but it takes about 5 seconds to open. (If I click on it opens very quickly.) Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @mb7744 Use `procmon` to find out

Answer (score 1):

In windows 11 I solved this by pinning git-bash to the taskbar:

"*Aside from letting you open your pinned taskbar apps with a click, you can also use keyboard shortcuts to launch them. You can do so by pressing the Windows Key + [ App Placement Number ]. So, if you want to open the first pinned app, press **Windows Key + 1**. To open the second pinned app, press **Windows Key + 2**, and so on*"

(https://www.makeuseof.com/ways-to-quickly-launch-apps-windows-11/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you.

Open Run ---> **Windows + R**

Type -------> **explorer shell:AppsFolder**

1. Then you found application folder. **Right click on desire App > Create Shortcut > Yes**
2. Go to your desktop and **right click on that app > Properties > Shortcut Key**
3. Now fill the shortcut key form with your desire key binding.

Hopefully you got your answer.

Thanks :)